# Unity Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity, using Unity 2019.3. I am trying to add back button functionality to my android game, but it's not working in Unity simulator nor mobile.

```
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Debug.Log("Back key pressed");
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Back key not pressed");
        }
```

I am continuously getting "Back key not pressed" log message.

Comment: Are you making a computer game or an android game? Your code looks fine. Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) is referring to the escape key being pressed down **on the computer.** If you want to add a button functionality to an android game, create a public function and assign it  to the button component.

Comment: He wrote it's an Android game.

Comment: It's an Android game, I am referring to physical back key in Android mobile.

Answer (score 0):

In the mobile devices you should rather use KeyCode.Return. Try this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
...
```

Also from my experience I recommend adding UI button for return anyway as there are devices that may not handle it properly.

Comment: I tried KeyCode.Return still not working. I am going to add a UI button but, I want to know why it is not working.

Comment: I attached the script to the main camera and called in update.